# How to define legend in matplotlib when there are no class labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, machine-learning

I need to draw an accuracy vs. parameters plot(the main task is to find best parameter values via grid search). Now, as there are a lot of parameter combinations, through which I am iterating; I thought of labeling each combination with its iteration number; and make the plot of accuracy vs the iteration numbers.

I do need to plot the accuracy against each combination of the parameter values.
But I also want to provide a legend with the plot which will have the parameter combination values against its respective iteration number.
How do this?

```
    parameters = parameterGrid(paramGrid)
    i = 0
    lst = []
    maxScore = 0


for parameter in parameters:
    meanAcc = 0

    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(**parameter)
    dTree = clf.fit(xTrain,yTrain)
    score = dTree.score(xTest, yTest)
    if(score > maxScore):
        maxScore = score
        selectedParams = parameter    
    plt.plot(i,score)
    #plotting accuracy against current parameter set 

    l = [i,score]
    lst.append(l)
    legend[i] = parameter
    i += 1



plt.xlabel('X Label')
plt.ylabel('Y Label')
plt.show()
```

Also, any other suggestions about how I should do the plotting is very much welcome. 
Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with using `plt.plot(..., label="blah")` and then `plt.legend()`?

Comment: If you post a bit of code, it is easier to help you. Building a list of labels constructed from indices, and assigning them to each dataset to be plotted should be easy to do.

Comment: @Julien - there's nothing wrong with using plt.plot() and then plt.legend(); but I am not getting how to put the desired information in the legend.
Also, plt.plot() gives me an empty plot; whereas plt.scatter is giving correct results. Can't understand why.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque - I edited my answer; and included the relevant code. please help.

Comment: @chi the legend should display the `label` as you define it (`'blah'` in my example) for each curve, so just put your 'desired information' there. If you need more help, we need a [mcve].

Comment: @Julien - Thanks you.

Comment: Great; I think jfried answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looping over the parameters you could use

```
iter = 0
for param1 in [1,2,3,4]:
 for param2 in [2,3,4,5]:
  plt.plot(..., label=str(param1)+"_"+str(param2)+"_"+str(iter))
  iter += 1
plt.legend()
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the code. Please have a look at it.
plt.plot(x,y) is giving me an empty plot; but plt.scatter is working. I am not getting why.

Comment: plt.plot() is a line plot so it doesn't really make sense to have a single point on a line plot. plt.scatter() is probably what you want to use. You can use the same method to create a legend.

Comment: I dont want to have a single point; for each parameter combination- there's an accuracy; so there are multiple points. So a line graph is more suitable, I guess.

Comment: What you are plotting right now is a single point with (x,y) coordinates (i, score) and you are doing this over and over again. If you want to make a line plot you need to use lists. E.g. plt.plot([1,2],[4,5]) will make a line between the points with (x,y) coordinates (1,4) and (2,5).